# Debian clean with deborphan

Tags: debian, package-management

```
Linux test 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-11-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Keep Getting message like this:

> /usr/bin/gdbus: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol:
>   g_date_copy

cannot understand what's wrong looking at:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/gdbus
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb53e7000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30f27fe000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30f27aa000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30f27a4000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f30f2495000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f30f22d8000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f30f2264000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f30f2241000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f30f2237000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f30f2019000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f30f1df1000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f30f1dd8000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f30f1d7c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f30f1d75000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f30f29d2000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f30f1d23000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f30f1d19000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f30f1d10000)
```

Installed # deborphan

```
coinor-libcoinmp1
libabw-0.1-1
libapt-inst1.5
libasprintf0c2
libavformat56
libboost-date-time1.58.0
libcdr-0.1-1
libclucene-contribs1v5
libcmis-0.5-5v5
libcryptsetup4
libe-book-0.1-1
libegl1-mesa-drivers
libelfg0
libeot0
libetonyek-0.1-1
libevent-extra-2.0-5
libevent-openssl-2.0-5
libevent-pthreads-2.0-5
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libfbembed2.5
libfreehand-0.1-1
libgdbm3
libglew1.10
libglib2.0-cil-dev
libglib2.0-tests
libgltf-0.0-0v5
libgnutls-openssl27
libgphoto2-port10
libgtop2-7
libicu52
libirs-export91
libisl10
libjim0.75
libjson-c2
liblogging-stdlog0
libmspub-0.1-1
libmwaw-0.3-3
libmythes-1.2-0
libodfgen-0.1-1
libopenvg1-mesa
liborcus-0.8-0
libplist2
libpostproc52
libprocps3
libpsl0
libpython3.4
libqpdf13
librdf0
libspectre1
libswscale3
libtorrent-rasterbar7
libturbojpeg1
libustr-1.0-1
libvala-0.34-0
libvisio-0.1-1
libwebpdemux1
libwebpmux1
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.3-3
ure
```

Those are all main lib, what can I do? 
Allow deborphan to work on those?